# Clear IIS Express cache for IE because of AJAX error

Tags: visual-studio, internet-explorer, browser-cache

I'm using Ajax Control Toolkit for a web project. I get the error when I debug the project with the internet explorer:

> Type.registerNamespace("AjaxControlToolkit")

I tried a lot until I find out that the error only occurs on my local IE. When I debug the project with chrome or firefox it is working fine.

So I cleared all options in the IE menu for clearing the cache. But the error still occurs.

I uploaded the project to the webserver and open it with the IE. Here no error occurs so the problem must be local.

Is there a hidden directory for caching with visual studio for the IE? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, please check the Local IE browser version, make sure it supports the AjaxControlTookit.

Then, Please try to use the following methods:

- Make sure the Local IE browser enable JavaScript.

  On the web browser menu, click Tools or the "Tools" icon (which looks like a gear), and select Internet Options. On the "Security" tab, make sure the Internet zone/Local intranet is selected, and then click on the "Custom level..." button.In the Security Settings – Internet Zone dialog box, click Enable for Active Scripting in the Scripting section. Click the OK apply the change.
- Reset IE browser setting.

  1. Close all open windows and programs.
  2. Open Internet Explorer, select Tools  > Internet options.
  3. Select the Advanced tab.
  4. In the Reset Internet Explorer Settings dialog box, select Reset.
  5. In the box, Are you sure you want to reset all Internet Explorer settings?, select Reset.
  6. When Internet Explorer finishes applying default settings, select Close, and then select OK. Restart your PC to apply changes.
- Reinstall IE browser.